# NHibernate: using c# doubles with SQL Server as "floats"

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I am using NH to map c#-double values into SQL Server 2005 as floats.
Everything works perfectly fine, however recently I tried running the `SchemaValidator`.

`SchemaValidator` fails:

```
Found: float, Expected DOUBLE PRECISION
```

Creating the tables using `DOUBLE PRECISION` works, but SQL Server will report the columns as `float`

Am I missing something here, or is this a (minor) bug in NHibernates type-Mapping?

**EDIT:**
This bug is fixed in the 2014-06-27 release: NHibernate-4.0.0.Alpha2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float(53) or just float in SQL Server has the same precision as C# double, so it would be a bug in the validator.

Comment: Um, yea but then problem is not the c# double but the difference between (sql) float(53) and (sql) double precision.

Comment: That isn't a problem, though. Float(53) and Double are both 64-bit floating point types. The problem is the validator.

Comment: It seems you're right (though I do not see it that way) - I opened an issue at nhforge (issue NH-2655) which was closed as "external issue" without comment. Since I doubt it means that this is an issue with sql-server only the validator can be meant by "external".

Comment: For the sake of completeness: My old issue ( https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2655 ) was re-opened in 2012 - so someone agreed with me that tis was indeed an error in NHibernate. The error was fixed ( https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2655?focusedCommentId=31753&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-31753 ) in Feb. 2014 https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/8de813ceb8c3e237d4fff4d975ba937c01238dfd#diff-291fb0d6ca7f8275bc2d722d5d532a3c